# WCF: Service to service call

Tags: wcf

Suppose i have following WCF Services.

UtilityService (Service to provide utility functions)

SomeOtherService 1

SomeOtherService 2

SomeOtherService 3

what is the best design to Use UtilityService in other services.

All services are exposed on separate endpoints...

Comment: why would you not just consume it as any other client does?  you might be able to share libraries and use strongly typed service calls without DTOs if the utility service is never publicly exposed, but I'd have thought that just using in the same way as any client would is the best option.

Comment: U mean add service reference of UtilityService in other WCF Service?

Comment: yes, or create a channel factory directly in your code, if you are sharing libraries

Comment: Any example of Channel Factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are those services in the same application? If yes create the instance of the service class directly instead of using all the WCF infrastructure! If they are not in the same application (and you don't share service assembly) you must use *Add service reference* as with any other WCF service.

Comment: UtlityService is added as reference to Other wcf services. it means that i can create instance of UtilityService??

Comment: Yes, you can - that is class as any other. The only exception is if you are using something directly related to WCF processing inside of `UtilityService`. For example `OperationContext.Current` will return context of your outer service.